# Not able to add the extension method using linq in the predicate builder

Tags: c#

```
Expression<Func<PartJoinTable, bool>> predicate = null;

var query2 = query.Join(
   partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery(),
  "x.PartID", 
  "PartID", 
  "inner" + row + "", 
   null);

predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query2);
```

This is the code for `PredicateBuilder`:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakePredicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return null;
    }
         public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>(IQueryable<T> query) { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>(IQueryable<T> query) { return f => false; }
```

Error message:

> The type arguments for method
>   'PredicateBuilder.True(IQueryable)' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<PartJoinTable>(query2);`

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PartDomain.Model.Models.PartJoinTable>'

Comment: make

`var query2 = query.Join(
   partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery(),
  "x.PartID", 
  "PartID", 
  "inner" + row + "", 
   null).Cast<PartJoinTable>();`

Comment: No coercion operator is defined between types '<>f__AnonymousType5`1[PartDomain.Model.Models.PartJoinTable]' and 'PartDomain.Model.Models.PartJoinTable'.'

Comment: var query =
                         (from x in partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery()
                          join y in partRepository.GetPartsQuery() on x.PartId equals y.Id
                          join z in partProductTypeReposiotry.GetPartProductTypesQuery() on x.PartId equals z.PartId
                          where y.IsSkipped == 0 && (y.IsDisabled != "Y" || y.IsDisabled == null) && z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate
                          && x.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
                          select new { x }).Cast<PartJoinTable>();

Comment: int lst1 = query.Distinct().Count();

Comment: when I try to get the count I am getting the above error